# What is the protocol that Android uses to upgrade OBEX connection to WiFi?

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth, obex

When I send file over Bluetooth (via share) between 2 Samsung phones it will show a toast that says:

> Automatically switched from Bluetooth to Wi-Fi Direct for fast file sharing.

Does anyone know what kind of protocol is used for this?

I didn't find this string in Android AOSP sources nor anything relevant in [BluetoothOppTransferActivity.java](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/modules/Bluetooth/android/app/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/BluetoothOppTransferActivity.java).
Is it a proprietary modification from Samsung or Google?

Comment: Looks like Samsung proprietary protocol: Galaxy Quick Share.